# Managing transactions with AllegroGraph's Jena API

Tags: jena, triplestore, allegrograph

I'm uncertain as to the behaviour of the AllegroGraph triple store in regard to transactions. [The tutorial](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/java-tutorial/java-tutorial-40.html#Transaction) talks about using two connections, but does not mention Jena models.

If I use Model's begin(), commit(), and abort() methods, do I still need to use two connections? How does a model interact with the connection's auto-commit setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jena tutorial](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/java-tutorial/jena-tutorial-40.html) doesn't have an example of transactions, but they are supported by using the Model methods: begin, commit, and abort.

You don't have to do anything manually with 2 connections.  I'll work on clarifying the language in the tutorial.

The way it's implemented, when you call begin(), it calls setAutoCommit(false).

Comment: Are transactions isolated from each other at the persistent store level?